# Yarn 2: `yarn version check` during CI always errors

Tags: github-actions, yarnpkg-v2

When running `yarn version check` locally everything goes smoothly and reports issues correctly, however when our Github Action runs it we get [the following error](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/9e90f18b9201fece1a1c7aee41d5db5b27c8d902/packages/plugin-version/sources/versionUtils.ts#L36):

```yml
YN0001: UsageError: No ancestor could be found between any of HEAD and main, origin/main, upstream/main
```

Our `yarnrc.yml` looks as follows:

```yml
changesetBaseRefs:
  - main
  - origin/main
  - upstream/main

changesetIgnorePatterns:
  - '**/*.test.{ts,tsx}'
  - '**/*.stories.{ts,tsx}'

nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: '@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools'
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript.cjs
    spec: '@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript'
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-version.cjs
    spec: '@yarnpkg/plugin-version'

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-berry.js
```

Our Github Action is as follows:

```yml
name: Version

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn config get cacheFolder)"
      - uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn
      - name: Check
        run: yarn bump:check
```

I thought perhaps because the `pull_request` action checks out the merge commit may be the issue and after reading "[a deep dive into pull_request](https://frontside.com/blog/2020-05-26-github-actions-pull_request/)", I tried adding the following to our action without luck:

```yml
with:
  ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

Any help understanding what we're doing wrong here would be super appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your checkout to fetch the [entire git history](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches). It will take longer, but it seems that this command needs that across multiple branches and tags.

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```